# How to hide "No Options Available" in the flyout button (Microsoft Dynamic 365) when no options to display?

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm, crm-ribbon-workbench, dynamic365

I want to hide "No Options Available" from the flyout button when there is no options to display. Currently I'm referring the [link](https://www.kashanahmed.com/2018/08/dynamic-flyout-menu-in-unified_15.html) to populate the flyout options dynamically. Before adding the buttons to menuXml directly, I'm making an API call, based on the API response (Boolean) I'm adding the button. If the response is false, I'm not adding any of the button to menuXml. So whenever the response is false, "No Options Available" is displaying when user clicks on the flyout button. If anyone knows how to hide that option, kindly provide the solution for that.

Answer (score 0):

Add Enable rule to your flyout button, make this rule as JavaScript rule and return true/false based on your operation. Ex: whenever the response is false, "No Options Available" Then return as false in your Enable rule javascript else True. Let me know if this helps